# Removing UIBarButtonItem's text shadow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I have adjusted a UIBarButtonItem to have custom font and color properties using

```
self.followButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]

                             initWithTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"TWITTER_FOLLOW_BUTTON_TEXT", nil)
                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                             target:self
                             action:@selector(handleFollowButtonPressed:)]
                            autorelease];
```

,

```
[self.followButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

,

```
[followButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0], UITextAttributeFont,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.176 blue:0.333 alpha:1 /*#ff2d55*/ ]};

    [followButton setTitleTextAttributes:attributes
                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

to get the appearance of

[image]

How can I remove the buttonitem's text shadow without resorting to changing it for an image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `UIBarButtonItem`'s `UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset` attribute to `UIOffsetMake(0.0, 0.0)`.

You'll need to store the `UIOffset` in an `NSValue` object: `[NSValue valueWithUIOffset: UIOffsetMake(0.0, 0.0)]`.

Comment: thank you! So I thought I should use     
[followButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0], UITextAttributeFont, [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(0.0,0.0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
Instead of the first part but it doesn't change it, what's wrong?

Comment: According to the docs for `UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset`, the value wrapped in the `NSValue` should be a `UIOffset`, not a `CGSize`. So you need to use `[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0,0)]`.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you could just set UITextAttributeTextShadowColor to [UIColor clearColor]

```
@{UITextAttributeTextShadowColor : [UIColor clearColor]}
```